# Bootstrap hover dropdown doesn't work "onhover", when hover from top or bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/mxLjutat/8/

I'm new in front-end. As you could see, there are two problems:

1. `<li>` elements doesn't appear. (It's not important, because in my original web site this part is working fine)
2. This is the main problem: onhover event is not working correctly. If you'll try to hover from the left or right side - it'll work fine, but if you'll try to hover from above or from below - it'll not work in general. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The li element is appearing, but the height of .right-top__box__menu__block is too small to see anything.

2) You just need to add the display property block to the anchor class.

```
.right-top__box__menu__block__list__link {
    color: #333;
    font: 12px/12px arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: block;
}
```